# Is there a way to extract the security advisories of a GitHub repository to a CSV file?

Tags: github, github-api

I am trying to extract data from the security advisories of a GitHub repository (Tensorflow is a good example with many advisories) to a CSV file which I can use for data analysis. I've looked at the GitHub API and PyGithub and could not find a way to extract this specific data.

[image: The security advisories I would like to extract from the repository]

I would also like to order them with their severity. Is there an API based method to do this or do I have to use a different method or sort the data manually? If I cannot extract from the repository itself, is there a way to extract from the GitHub advisory database? https://github.com/advisories?query=tensorflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the full GitHub Advisory Data from the repository below:

https://github.com/github/advisory-database

then process it into any format as you wish.